# Display controls based on property in StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a `StackPanel` with three `TextBlock`s in a Windows Phone app, on a page that looks some thing like this:

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock></TextBlock>
   <TextBlock></TextBlock>
   <TextBlock></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Based on a property value I would like to display any one of the `TextBlock`s. Suppose if I have a property named as "Name" and if this property's value is "1" I would like to display only the first `TextBlock` similarly for 2 and 3. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: is it possible to have one text block then change the text and position? Edit: otherwise a switch statement depending on propertycontent if its always a number

Comment: No i cannot change may be i can have different controls.. so i cannot change text and position

Comment: Can you please explain the scenario for  2 and 3 as it is not clear from just 1.

Comment: For 2 i need to display second textblock and for 3 i need to display third textblock

Answer (score 0):

Bind Visiblity to a property on your model and use a converter:
http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/talking-about-converters-in-wp7--coding4fun-toolkit-converters-in-depth

```
public class IntToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   int intValue (int)value;

    if(intValue == 1)
return Visibility.Visible;
else
return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

}

Comment: thank you for ur answer.If i have 10 textblocks and if i want to display 2 in that if the property content is "5" then i think i cannot use this one...